# Scope Propagation & ng-repeat="i in [1]"

Tags: angularjs

So I've been reading the AngularJS documentation to grasp a better fundamental understanding of the language however I'm completely thrown with this code.

In regards to the ng-repeat="i in [1]"

```
    angular.module('plnkrCode',[]);

    https://plnkr.co/edit/pO7rBE978ysWgCbTd8Yo?p=preview
```

Where is it referencing this index of [1] from? What is it in relation to?

I should note for further clarification that this part of the documentation is in regards to scope event propagation if that helps.

Any feedback on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nothing special. ng-repeat create a new element per item in array. `[1]` is an array with only one value in it (1). So it just create the `<li` only once.

But, what is the relation to scope event propagation?

> Each instance of the repetition is given its own scope, which consist
>   of the current item.

So you can use `EventController` multiple times on different scopes.

Comment: Ahh I see I had no idea you could create an array for it to iterate through in the HTML, I thought it had to be referenced from a $scope within the ctrl, your feedback is much appreciated.